# Limit access to rewritten uri based on IP address

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, authentication

I'd like to limit access to a Drupal 7 registration page (/user/register) from certain IP addresses.

I've tried to set the apache directive, but it's still letting me access it from an IP that isn't specified.

Here's a snippet of my virtualhost directive

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName ######
    ServerAlias ######
    ErrorLog logs/######-error_log
    CustomLog logs/######-access_log combined

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://######%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,L]

    <Location /user/register>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from ***.***.***.***
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are redirecting all requests to HTTPS (port 443 by default), but your `<Location>` directive is in the `<VirtualHost *:80>` container (port 80 - HTTP).

Aside... the `<Location>` directive is generally not recommended for restricting access since resources can often be accessed by multiple URLs, circumventing the restriction. (For instance, you'll also need to make sure the rewritten URL is also blocked.)

You also don't need `?%{QUERY_STRING}` in the `RewriteRule` substitution. The query string is appended by default.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of things you can try that I'll show starting with the easiest:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ServerName ######
ServerAlias ######
ErrorLog logs/######-error_log
CustomLog logs/######-access_log combined

<Location /user/register>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from ***.***.***.***
</Location>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ServerName ######
ServerAlias ######
ErrorLog logs/######-error_log
CustomLog logs/######-access_log combined

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://######%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,L]

<Location /user/register>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from ***.***.***.***
</Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

What I did was basically copy everything into a virtual host container for HTTPS so that your settings apply for both HTTP AND HTTPS.

Another option is to modify the contents of the script that serves the document you want to protect so that it blocks out accesses from unacceptable IP addresses.

If its in PHP, you can add the following line directly under `<?php`:

```
If ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"){echo "Access denied";exit();}
```

Replace xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx with the IP address to accept. If you want two IP addresses instead, you can add this line:

```
If ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" && $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != "yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy"){echo "Access denied";exit();}
```